# How to load Collection of models in Backbone View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I'm trying to learn [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) and for this I now want to load a collection of models into a view. By opening a tab in the window, I first add the following template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tab-content-template">
    <div class="conversation-window" id="conversation<%= ticketId %>"></div>
</script>
```

In this tempalte I now want to load a Collection of messages belonging to the ticketId. So I made a collection like this:

```
var MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'ticket/:id/messages'
});
```

and a view:

```
var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.ticketId = options.ticketId;
    },
    el: function() {
        return '#conversation' + this.ticketId;
    },
    className: 'user-message'
});
```

So I want the list of messages to be inserted within the #conversation1 (for ticketId 1). I then tried running this:

```
var messageView = new MessageView(messageCollection, {ticketId: 1});
messageView.render();
console.log(messageView);
```

Unfortunately nothing happens, and when I look into the console I see that `ticketId: 1` but that `el: undefined`. I'm kinda lost in what I'm doing wrong (kinda lost in Backbone in general).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here and how I can solve it? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're running a `fetch()` on your collection to populate the models within it, although I do see you pass in the `messageCollection` to the `MessageView` (though I usually set that to the `collection` rather than `models`).  Also, I don't see a direct link to your template within your view.  I'm not sure if you want to see the models with the data, or the rendering of the page?

Comment: If you define `el` in your View, you're telling Backbone to manage an existing element - in this case, the element with ID 'conversation1'. That element is within the template you posted at the top of your message. Are you definitely rendering that to your page before you instantiate your messageView?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<div id = "conversation1">stuff insert here</div>
<script>
  var MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //  url: 'ticket/:id/messages'   //<-- put this in router
  });

  // you need to create an instance of you collection somewhere and pass in
  // models as parameter. note that your ticketId is included in the models:
  var messageCollection = new MessageCollection([{ticketId:1,attr:'stuff1'}, {ticketId:2,attr:'stuff1'}])


  var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.ticketId_1 = this.collection.models[0].get('ticketId');
        this.ticketId_2 = this.collection.models[1].get('ticketId');
    },
    // can not reference el and define a <div id="user-message"> simultaneously
    /*
    el: function() {
        return '#conversation' + this.ticketId;
    }, 
    */
    className: 'user-message',
    render: function() {
        $('#conversation'+ this.ticketId_1).html(this.$el.html('stuff from model goes in here'));
    }
});

// var messageView = new MessageView( messageCollection, {ticketId: 1});
// the above wouldn't work. your ticketId should be passed into your view via model
// then you associate you view to your collection like so: 
var messageView = new MessageView({ collection: messageCollection });
messageView.render();
console.log(messageView.$el.html());

</script>
```